# Using Express as RESTful Gateway for AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda

I'm currently building an application built on top of AWS lambda functions, and am wanting to use Express as a middleware and gateway for requests that will then be passed to lambda.

However, I'm wondering if there is any risk in my setup below. Basically, I am defining all the acceptable routes, using router.all('/*') to catch every request, and then if the requested route is in the routes object and requested method is correct, it will authenticate the user and then run the lambda function. I will also add logic for authentication, which data to send to lambda, etc.

My questions are:

1. Is it acceptable to pass the res object to the lambda execution function?
2. Would it be better to authenticate in a different place, or is it fine to do so within the router.all function?
3. Are there any concerns with scalability/handling of many requests using this simple framework?

   ```
   const express        = require('express');
   const app            = express();
   var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

   var router = express.Router();

   const routes = {
   'lambdaFunctionA': { 'method' : 'POST', 'data' : 'body'},
   'lambdaFunctionB': {'method' : 'GET', 'data' : 'queryParams'},
   'lambdaFunctionC': {'method' : 'GET'}
   }

   router.all('/*', function (req, res) {

     const path = req.path.split('/')[1];

     if (path in routes) {

       if ( routes[path].method == req.method ) {
           //authentication logic here 
           //if authenticated, execute lambda
           executeLambda(path,someDataHere, res);
       }
       else
       {
           res.status(405).send('Method not allowed');
       }
     }
     else
     {
         res.status(404).send('Not found');
     }
   });

   app.use('/api', router);

   app.listen(8080);

   function executeLambda(functionName,payload, res) {

       var params = {
         FunctionName: functionName,
         Payload: payload
       };

       var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();      
       lambda.invoke(params, function (err, data) {
         if (err) {
           //need to handle errors here
           res.send(err.stack);
         } else {
           res.send(JSON.parse(data.Payload));
         }
       });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use express's builtin functionality to do this instead of doing yourself? No need to invent your own routing when express comes with it built-in

```
function lambdaHandler(req, res){
    executeLambda(path, someDataHere, res);
}
function auth(next){
    //...Do auth stuff
   if(!auth) return next("router");
   next();
}
router.use(auth);
router.post("/lambdaFunctionA", lambdaHandler)
router.get("/lambdaFunctionB", lambdaHandler)
router.get("/lambdaFunctionC", lambdaHandler)
```

Lookup [express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router)

This way you get Express to handle the methods etc for you instead of having to handle it yourself. It can also validate.

And on every request it uses the middleware from `router.use(auth)` to authenticate before it ever gets to `lambdaHandler`

Also it is perfectly fine to pass `res` to the lambda handler. It's just an object.

---

As a side note:

Have you seen [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)?

It can handle routing and uses lambdas just like in your use case. Without having to manage your own server.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Although how would i handle path parameters vs query params vs request data in this way? I thought it would be eaay to set that up in my routes object and then my router would take care of it. I will read up on the middleware  component though. And I'm not able to utilize API Gateway for unrelated reasons, or else I would be doing this there.

Comment: Express doesn't come with much in the box but here is a github repo that attempts to handle validation https://github.com/AndrewKeig/express-validation

Comment: Thanks, but to clarify what I mean by that, what if from LambdaFunctionA I want to use query params, and from LambdaFunctionB I want to use path params? From my original design I can handle that from my routes object. What is your suggestion to easily and dynamically handle this from "router.post("/lambdaFunctionA", lambdaHandler)"? I could combine all params into one Payload object for the lambda function but I don't know if that is a best practice.

Comment: Well just make another handler before lambda handler that can process your specific items `router.post("/lambdaFunctionA/:path/:param", handler, lambdahandler)`